# Quadric proof exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

In the book of Geometry that I am studying in class there is a proposition (referring to Euclidean 3-dimensional space) that is left as an exercise. I don’t know how to tackle this problem, any help is appreciated, and sorry for my broken english.

---

*(a) Show that the geometric place of the points such that the sum of the squares of their  distances to two lines that cross (which  is constant) is a quadric surface.*

*(b) Also show that the geometric place of the points $p$ such that $d(p,r) = d(p,s)$ where $r,s$ are two lines that cross, is a quadric surface.*

---

Edit (1)

With the help of @Robert Z I understood how to compute the problem, but I don’t know how to draw the conclusion that the final computation implies that there is a quadric.

---

Edit (2)

So computing $d(p,r)^2 + d(p,s)^2 = k$ I arrived to the general equation of the quadric in function of the terms $x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, yz, xz, x,y,z$: $$c_{11}x^2 + c_{22}y^2 + c_{33}z^2 + 2c_{12}xy + 2c_{13}xz + 2c_{23}yz + 2c_{01}x + 2c_{02}y + 2c_{03}z + c_{00} = 0$$ where the terms $c_{ij}$ are the constants derived from the $a_i$ from $d(p,r)^2$, and the $b_i$ are the constants from $d(p,s)^2$

---

**Possible solution**

I recalled from Lineal Algebra that the distance from a point $p = (x, y, z)$ to a hyperplane (which in this case, is a line) $r: a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_3 = b$ where $r = L[u]$, $u = (a_1, a_2, a_3)$ (for the purpose of the computations it is convenient to take $u$ such that $||u|| = 1)$ is $$d(p,r) = \frac{|a_1x + a_2y + a_3z - b|}{\sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2 +a_3^2}}$$

So, doing the same to the hyperplane $s$, we get that $$d(p,s) = \frac{|b_1x + b_2y + b_3z - d|}{\sqrt{b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2}}$$

So, now we apply the hypothesis: $$d(p,s)^2 + d(p,r)^2 = k \iff \frac{(b_1x + b_2y + b_3z - d)^2}{b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2} + \frac{(a_1x + a_2y + a_3z - b)^2}{a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2} = k \iff (b_1x + b_2y + b_3z - d)^2 + (a_1x + a_2y + a_3z - b)^2 = k$$

The factors $b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2$ and $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2$ "vanish" because we defined $||u|| = ||(a_1, a_2, a_3)|| = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 = 1$ and for $||v|| = ||(b_1, b_2, b_3)|| = 1$

And from here, by expanding the sum of the squares, taking common factor on the constants that multiply the factors $x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, yz, xz, x, y, z$ and doing a change of variables, we arrive to the general form of a quadric surface.
$$c_{11}x^2 + c_{22}y^2 + c_{33}z^2 + 2c_{12}xy + 2c_{13}xz + 2c_{23}yz + 2c_{01}x + 2c_{02}y + 2c_{03}z + c_{00} = 0$$

I think all the steps are correct but it is late and my brain is tired, so who knows? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: by expanding the complication expression of $d(P,r)^2$ in Robert Z's answer, you get a linear combination of $6$ terms $x^2,y^2,z^2,xy,yz,zx$ with coefficient determined by the $a_i$. These $a_i$ are parameters and independent of what $(x,y,z)$ are (i.e constants for the surface) By definition, a quadric surface is the zero set of linear combinations of 10 terms, above $6$ terms together with $x,y,z$ and a constant term.

Comment: @achillehui But how do you “compress” all these computations together in order to express it as the general form equation of the quadric?

Comment: You don't need to know how to carry out the computation nor what is the finite form of coefficient. What you need to know is the coefficient are "constants" for the purpose of the definition. i.e. their values are independent of what $(x,y,z)$ are.

Comment: I think I got it. Adding both distances and taking the common factor in function of $x^2, y^2, z^2, xy, zy, xz$ and changing the variables would eventually lead to the general form of a quadric (which can be expressed as a product of matrices). Is that correct?

Comment: But since they are all constant why is it safe to assume that k can be 0? By the choice of the basis?

Comment: Hmm... I misread the expression of $d(P,r)^2$, when you expand it, it has all 10 possible terms for quadric surface. About the question of $k$. No, you don't assume it is zero, you just move it to other side of equation.

Comment: @achillehui Okay, got it. Why are there 9 $a_i$ Instead of 6?

Comment: The line $P_1P_2$ need not pass through the origin.

Comment: But being in the 3D space any point P is represented by 3 coordinates, and since we have two points $P_1, P_2$ These would be expressed as $P_1 = (a_1, a_2, a_3), P_2 = (a_4, a_5, a_6)$ Where am I wrong?

Comment: The three 3-tuples doesn't come from $P_1$, $P_2$ directly. It comes from the three components of the cross product. e.g. the first 3-tuple $a_1 y + a_2 z + a_3$ comes from the $x$-component of the cross product. that's why it doesn't have a $x$ in it.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, [the distance from a point $P=(x,y,z)$ and a line $r$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html) is
$$d(P,r)=\frac{\|(P-P_1)\times (P-P_2)\|}{\|P_2-P_1\|}$$
where $P_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $P_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ are two distinct points along $r$. Therefore, after expanding the cross product, we find that
$$\begin{align}d(P,r)^2&=\frac{1}{||P_2-P_1\|^2}\left|\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k}\\ 
x-x_1 & y-y_1 & z-z_1 \\ 
x-x_2 & y-y_2 & z-z_2 
\end{vmatrix}\right|^2\\
&=(a_1y+a_2z+a_3)^2+(a_4x+a_5z+a_6)^2+(a_7x+a_8y+a_9)^2
\end{align}$$
where $a_1,\dots, a_9$ are numbers which depend on $x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2$.

Now, for (a), we have that
$$d(P,r)^2+d(P,s)^2=k$$
where $k$ is a given positive constant, whereas for (b), the equation to be satisfied can be written as
$$d(P,r)^2 = d(P,s)^2.$$
What kind of algebraic equations (with respect to $x$, $y$, $z$) do we find in each case?

Comment: But aren’t we in the 3-dimensional space? Wouldn’t you need $P=(X,Y,Z)$?

Comment: @AngusL Sorry, you are right, I missed the "space" word.

Comment: I’m trying to compute the sum of the squares of the distances but I don’t seem to got anywhere...

Comment: What is the general form of a quadric surface? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric

Comment: Sorry I couldn’t answer earlier, I still don’t see where are you trying to get by expanding the vector product. I can see that after expanding both $d(p,r)^2$, $d(p,s)^2$ and adding them up you will  end with a expression depending on the point P and the two points from r and s but how do you conclude that this formula in the end is the formula for a quadric? Thanks and sorry.

Comment: I think I finally managed to get the general equation of the quadric by expanding the sum of the squares of the distances and taking common factor of $a_1, ..., a_9$ and $b_1,...,b_9$(which are the constant of the points $Q_1, Q_2$ from the line s. But what I don’t understand now is why do you have 9 a’s? There are only $P_1, P_2$ Which have 3 coordinates since we are in the 3D space, which would lead to a total of 6 a’s: $a_1,...a_6$ Instead of $a_1,...,a_9$? How did you expand the vector product?

Comment: Note that $a_1,...,a_9$ are not independent, they are functions of the 3+3 coordinates of $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Comment: Im sorry, I don’t see it, could you expand the vector product in your answer so I can see it step by step? Thanks

Comment: @AngusL Your question has been closed because of "missing context or other details". I am trying to reopen it. Why don't you edit your question with what you did so far.

Comment: Already edited my post, and by the way in (b) the distances are not squared. Can you expand the vector product so I can see where did the $a_1,...,a_9$ come from, since I didn’t understand how you computed the distance?

Comment: By expanding the determinant I obtained my coefficients $a_i$.For example $((y-y_1)(z-z_2)-(y-y_2)(z-z_1))^2/\|P_2-P_1\|^2=(a_1y+a_2z+a_3)^2.$

Comment: Okay, and then, for (b) you have stated that the $d(p,r)^2=d(p,s)^2$ but instead, it should be $d(p,r)=d(p,s)$ since the proposition doesn't say anything about the distances being squared. But I don't know how to compute this since it is not squared.

Comment: Since distance is a non-negative function, $d(p,r)=d(p,s)$ holds if and only if $d(p,r)^2=d(p,s)^2$

Comment: I've been trying to get the same answer as you did when expanding the vector product but I don't see it. Please can you expand the one you did as an example in one of your last comments? Sorry and thank you

Comment: I updated my post with a possible solution, please tell me what do you think about it when you can. Thanks

Comment: You solved a different problem: a plane is NOT a line! Why don't you use the formula given in my answer?

Comment: Because I don’t understand how you computed the vector product

Comment: I totally messed up, you’re right, don’t know why I thought that a hyperplane ir R^3 is a line